# How to identify if a bot is added to contact?

Tags: chatbot, botframework

Out of these [message types](http://docs.botframework.com/connector/message-types/#navtitle), is there one to signify if a user newly adds a bot to  contact.

Answer (score 0):

We don't have that message at this time.  The closest is Bot or UserAddedToConversation.

Not all channels support contact relationships systemically.  It would be a good suggestion though; https://feedback.botframework.com.